# "If 'b4' in [['a4', 'b4', c4']]" returns False in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a line that states: if 'b4' in [['a4', 'b4', c4',...]]:. b4 is clearly in the list and still it returns False? How is this possible?
[if 'b4' in [['a4', 'b4', c4',...]]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThWXN.png)
[returns False](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGb21.png)

Comment: `'b4'` is *not* clearly in the list. Consider `x = ['a4', 'b4', 'c4']; if 'b4' in [x]: ...`. The list only has one value: is that value `'b4'`?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely because the list inside the if statement is actually a list of lists, and the string 'b4' is not in the outermost list, but rather in a nested list. To check if 'b4' is in the list of lists, you can use a nested loop to iterate through the outer list and then the inner lists, and check if 'b4' is in any of the inner lists.

```
lst = [['a4', 'b4', 'c4'], ['d4', 'e4', 'f4']]

for inner_lst in lst:
    if 'b4' in inner_lst:
        print(True)
        break
else:
    print(False)
```

This will return True.

Also you can use List comprehension for the same

```
lst = [['a4', 'b4', 'c4'], ['d4', 'e4', 'f4']]

print('b4' in [i for sublist in lst for i in sublist])
```

This will also return True

Alternatively, you can use the any() function and a generator expression, which is more concise and also more efficient:

```
lst = [['a4', 'b4', 'c4'], ['d4', 'e4', 'f4']]

print(any('b4' in sublist for sublist in lst))
```

Comment: More idiomatically, `print(any('b4' in x for x in lst))`.

Comment: Your list comprehension is inefficient, as it has to build the fully flattened list before beginning to check each element against `'b4'`. It doesn't let you short-circuit the search by ignoring sublists after the one `'b4'` is found in.

Comment: You are correct that the list comprehension in the example is inefficient, as it creates a fully flattened list before checking each element against 'b4'.
A more efficient way to check if 'b4' exists in the list of lists would be to use any() function and a generator expression, which is more concise and also more efficient.
thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Check the square brackets (you're effectively creating a nested list)

The correct code should be `if 'b4' in ['b4',...]`

Comment: What makes that correct? OP has a list of lists.

Comment: It's correct if the nested list is a typo. We don't know that, though.

Answer (score -1):

The string 'b4' is in a sub-list (you have a list if lists)

Perhaps this will clarify...

```
print('b4' in [['a4', 'b4', 'c4']][0])
```

**Output:**

```
True
```